# appending results into vector in for loop keeps overwriting the second item (R)

Tags: r

I have the Decathlon dataset (can get it with `install.packages("GDAdata")` and `data(Decathlon, package="GDAdata")`).
I'm trying to get the winning countries per year, so I'm trying to make a for loop that gets the maximum from the Totalpoints per year, gets the ID of that cell, gets the cell and appends it to an empty vector.

```
x<-c()
for (year in range(1985:2006)){
  fil <- filter(Decathlon, yearEvent==year)
  #colMax <- max(fil[,1])}
  id <- fil[which.max(fil[,1]),3] 
  country <- levels(fil$Nationality)[id]
  x <- c(x,country)
}
```

The problem is that this way only the first country in "x" is correct. The second one (which would correspond to 1986) keeps overwritting with every iteration, like this:

```
x
[1] "DDR" "USA"
```

Tried a few ways to do it and nothing worked... any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're using `filter` from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Instead of `range(1985:2006)` use `1985:2006` as you want to repeat your process over all those values

Comment: If you already use `dplyr` you can do: `Decathlon %>%
  group_by(yearEvent) %>%
  summarise(WinningCountry = Nationality[Totalpoints == max(Totalpoints)])`

Answer (score 0):

`range(1985:2006)` is equivalent to `c(1985L,2006L)`
You want simply `1985:2006`.